# vector layer is hide on rotation

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

In my project I create two layers, a tile layer and a vector layer. In the tile layer I load some image(e.g open aerial image), and then I create a frame around the tile layer using the vector layer.

The problem occurs when map rotates. When view rotation is 0, everything is OK.

[code that show the problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eugb9x)

P.S
this code was work perfectly fine on ol 5.0.3.

**update**

the problem was fix in this [PR](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/11190)

Comment: It looks like the vector layer extent option isn't working correctly, but do do not need it - simply remove `extent: this.mainLayer.getExtent(),`

Comment: in this case it may be right. but i also have a vector layer(not include in the above code) that draw annotations on the map, and i don't want  them be visible outside the image extent.

Comment: It looks like an OpenLayers bug.  Until it is fixed I think you would need to use `ol/layer/VectorImage` as a workaround